# need help getting form to submit/go from a submit area

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, forms

so I'm currently following this tutorial on PHP forms and ive made it to the bottom of this page where it says to test the form so far, http://www.webreference.com/programming/php/search/2.html
"Save your file and test your form at this point (search_display.php)."
When I go to type in a users name in thew design view of dreamweaver and hit submit nothing happens (as if the page is refreshing) however, when i navigate to my file from my MySQL  (XAMP and phpMyADmin) server directory i can view my search page but there is no text box/area for me to enter in any data. I have followed/copied this tutorial verbatim and im quite unsure on why I can not get my data to submit to the query. Here is the code for my search page

```html
<!DOCTYPE  HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
    <html> 
     <head> 
      <meta  http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;  charset=iso-8859-1"> 
       <title>Search  Contacts</title> 
     </head> 
        
    <p>
    <body> 
     <h3>Search  Contacts Details</h3> 
      <p>You  may search either by first or last name</p> 
      <form  method="post" action="search.php?go"  id="searchform">
        <p>
         <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
       </p>
     </form> 
    </body> 
        </p>
    </html>
```

Thanks guys for the help.

Comment: Form shown has no text input for user to fill out. Might do some web searches for `html form` to get a better understanding of various form controls themselves and how forms work in browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML form is missing a text field. Please check the HTML sample on the [first tutorial page](http://www.webreference.com/programming/php/search/index.html).

Side note: you really should not be following this tutorial as it is greatly outdated, teaches bad practices and will not work when using PHP 7+ due to the [removed mysql extension](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php).

Comment: ok sweet thanks man, I have no prior coding experience except what Ive learned off this site and others like it in the past 4 days so Ive been doing my best to learn with what i can find.
Do you know where i can find practice/examples of how to do this or something like it with the new php 7 ?

Comment: Some good sources of information are http://www.phptherightway.com/ and https://github.com/ziadoz/awesome-php

Answer (score 0):

*1. Place this code where you need the form. For example index.php . There is no input field in your form. So add input fields. For example i am adding email and mobile no as input fields*

```
<h3>Search  Contacts Details</h3> 
<p>You  may search either by first or last name</p> 
<form  method="post" action="search.php"  id="searchform">
<input  type="text" name="email" value="">
<input  type="text" name="mobileno" value="">
<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

*2. Create another page called search.php and place the below code here*

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mobileno = $_POST['mobileno'];
}
```

*Validate all the fields before inserting into database.*

Comment: Ok so I got the fields up but now when i go to search/submit, it is as if the form just refreshes the page and doesnt progress to the next php file.

Comment: You need to check this in browser. Not in dreamweaver design view. Can you tell me the location of the files.

Comment: All the files are located under C:\xampp\htdocs\myCode
to view the files i just enter localhost in the url bar, from there i click on myCode and it takes me to my index.php page which has a nav button which take me to the search.php (form) page and from there i have the text field that when i enter data into and hit select enter it appears to refresh the page however the url will show the http://localhost/myCode/search.php?go <--  now

Comment: You are sending the data to the same page. So you need to capture the post data on search.php page itself. Can you try to print_r($_POST); in search.php page which prints all the post values.

Comment: should i make a copy of the database's table data in the htdocs folder like as a CSV or something?

Comment: would i put that under the form action?

Comment: You can place that code above form also like this 
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mobileno = $_POST['mobileno'];
}
?>

Comment: I get a new error now when i go to submit a name
the usual error 404 web url not found

Comment: This is because the post page you are submitting is not matching with the file name. 404 page not found

Comment: ok, that makes sense now.   if currently it has action="search.start?go"     should I change it to  action="search_start.php?search_go.php"      in this case what does the ? mean since im copying it off the tutorial file.  My Post changes havent been peer reviewed

Comment: would this be a good source to use. http://hubpages.com/technology/Simple-search-PHP-MySQL     
 is more up-to-date than the current one i was using. I can just follow this one if you are getting tired of asnwering questions from me. would hate to be a burden to the community

Comment: I think its good to go through good tutorials mentioned on the other answer and learn how the form post work. After that jump into other feature like search or whatever. Once you understood the form concept you can get into the features you want. Good luck.

Comment: ok so for the first time in 5 days the program works like i want it to but when i search the fields that are echoed back to me and back to back. how do i insert breaks between them.  they are like 12372(704) 372-2487NC28031  but I would like them to be 12372   (704) 372-2487   NC   28031  or maybe even appear nicer. do you have any suggestions